# Assembly.LoadFrom locks assembly file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, reflection, add-in

Referencing this question: [System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile Locks File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031431/system-reflection-assembly-loadfile-locks-file)
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path) wont work since it's not a standalone lib, it has many dependencies.
This solution ( http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35494668/shadow-copies-how.aspx ) won't work either, since I'm writing a Visual Studio addin, and I have no access to a Main method.
The second answer here ( [Can I make the default AppDomain use shadow copies of certain assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373199/can-i-make-the-default-appdomain-use-shadow-copies-of-certain-assemblies) ) won't work either, since the problem described in comment, I need to be able to repeatedly reload the given assembly and always see the most fresh version, yet I still *must be able to rebuild the assembly without quiting the Visual Studio instance which runs my addin*.

What are my options?

Comment: Good luck, make sure you wear a bulletproof vest, you are heading for a dangerous neighborhood.

Comment: Use two instances of Visual Studio, one to build, another to test.  Restart the 2nd one as needed.

Comment: currently using a workaround: moved the code loading the assembly into a console exe, and copied the exe to a fixed location (set from addin config), and I'm calling AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly on that fixed location and then unloading that AppDomain... (and that appdomain uses shadowcopy just to be safe :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original comment turned permanent solution:
*moved the code loading the assembly into a console exe, and copied the exe to a fixed location (set from addin config), and I'm calling AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly on that fixed location and then unloading that AppDomain... (and that appdomain uses shadowcopy just to be safe :))*