# What is the right way to set shadow copying for the default AppDomain

Tags: .net, appdomain, shadow-copy, appdomainsetup

Relating to [Can I make the default AppDomain use shadow copies of certain assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373199/1684064), it describes a working solution to activate shadow copying within the default AppDomain for a specific directory.

Basically it says to use these simple methods:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetShadowCopyPath(aDirectory);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetShadowCopyFiles();
```

But because the methods used here are marked as obsolete I was wondering what is now the correct way to accomplish the same. The warning message hints to:

> Please investigate the use of AppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyDirectories instead

An AppDomain has a member of this type called `SetupInformation` which might bring  you to this straightforward implementation

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ShadowCopyDirectories = aDirectory;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
```

Unfortunately this has no effect.
So the question is, is there a way to alter the AppDomainSetup of the current appdomain to activate shadow copying ?

Comment: To answer the _"Unfortunately this has no effect. "_ (3 years after asking, I know), this is because the property `SetupInformation` creates a _clone_ of the internal `FusionStore` property which in turn is a reference to the actual `AppDomainSetup` used to initialize the current domain. The idea is that after initialization, these properties cannot be modified anymore (though I wonder why they haven't made them gettor-only to signify that).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know these methods only work on .NET Framework version 1.1. For all later versions you cannot enable shadow-copying on the main AppDomain. You need to create a new `AppDomain` and set-it up appropriately. A simple approach is to create a loader application that simply:

- **Creates a new AppDomain with shadow-copy enabled**. For this you will have to use one of the overloads of [AppDomain.CreateDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.createdomain.aspx) that take an [AppDomainSetup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.aspx) parameter.
- **Executes your main application** using the [AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.executeassembly.aspx) method.

A good starting point can be found in the [Shadow Copying of Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29961/Shadow-Copying-of-Applications) CodeProject article. The following program is taken from the article with a slight modification (the cache path is not specified:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Loader
{
    static class Program
    {
        [LoaderOptimization(LoaderOptimization.MultiDomainHost)]
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            /* Enable shadow copying */

            // Get the startup path. Both assemblies (Loader and
            // MyApplication) reside in the same directory:
            string startupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(
                System.Reflection.Assembly
                .GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            string configFile = Path.Combine(
                startupPath,
                "MyApplication.exe.config");
            string assembly = Path.Combine(
                startupPath,
                "MyApplication.exe");

            // Create the setup for the new domain:
            AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
            setup.ApplicationName = "MyApplication";
            setup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true"; // note: it isn't a bool
            setup.ConfigurationFile = configFile;

            // Create the application domain. The evidence of this
            // running assembly is used for the new domain:
            AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
                "MyApplication",
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
                setup);

            // Start MyApplication by executing the assembly:
            domain.ExecuteAssembly(assembly);

            // After the MyApplication has finished clean up:
            AppDomain.Unload(domain);
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to:

- Replace `MyApplication.exe` with the name of your executable assembly.
- Replace `MyApplication` with the name of apllication.
- Replace `MyApplication.exe.config` with the name of you application's configuration file. If you do not have one then you do not need to set this.

Comment: You can do this for asp.net project.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a separate application. You can just spawn sub-domain in your main method or call the actual main method based on `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsDefaultAppDomain()` value:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsDefaultAppDomain())
    {
        // Loader
        var entryPoint = System.Reflection.Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly();

        var applicationName = entryPoint.GetName().Name;
        // Create the setup for the new domain:
        var setup = new AppDomainSetup();
        setup.ApplicationName = applicationName;
        setup.ShadowCopyFiles = "true"; // note: it isn't a bool

        // Create the application domain. The evidence of this
        // running assembly is used for the new domain:
        AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
           applicationName,
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
            setup);

        try
        {
            // Start MyApplication by executing the assembly:
            domain.ExecuteAssembly(entryPoint.Location, args);
        }
        finally
        {
            // After the MyApplication has finished clean up:
            AppDomain.Unload(domain);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Main
        ActualMain(args);
    }
}

public static int ActualMain(string[] args)
{
     //Hello-world!
}
```