# Replaceable assemblies for plugin

Tags: c#, mef, system.componentmodel

we are trying to hot swap (update) assemblies, the normal workflow is that we make some changes, build the assembly, do some changes and build again and in an ideal world the host app would get the new version of the assembly (with the updated types).

Here's our small plugin loader class:

```
public class PluginLoader<T>
{
    private CompositionContainer _compositionContainer;
    private RegistrationBuilder _registrationBuilder;
    private DirectoryCatalog _catalog;

    [ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true)]
    public IList<T> Plugins { get; set; }

    public PluginLoader(string pluginsDirectory)
    {
        Plugins = new List<T>();
        SetShadowCopy();

        _registrationBuilder = new RegistrationBuilder();
        _registrationBuilder
           .ForTypesDerivedFrom(typeof(T))
           .SetCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)
           .Export<T>();

        _catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(pluginsDirectory, _registrationBuilder);

        _compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(_catalog, CompositionOptions.DisableSilentRejection);
        _compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    public void Reload()
    {
        _catalog.Refresh();
        _compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    private static void SetShadowCopy()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetShadowCopyFiles();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetCachePath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, "ShadowCopyCache"));
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetShadowCopyPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, "Plugins"));
    }
}
```

We have code to recognize a new plugin dropping into the plugins folder using FileSystemWatcher, and we call Reload when that happens, **but the new versions of assemblies aren't actually loaded**.
Any pointers?

Notes:

- No new or deleted types are recognized, it's as if it doesn't recognize the new assembly at all.
- We checked and there are no composition and other errors either, so we are a bit lost :D
- It is important to note that if we build the same non recognized assembly with a different compiler(Roslyn), then it is recognized (which points to nothing being badly setup, just that the assembly needs to be somehow different )

Answer (score 1):

The methods called in `SetShadowCopy` are deprecated. You cannot enable ShadowCopy on an existing `AppDomain`. For an example on how to enable ShadowCopy on a new AppDomain, Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343056/850119).

[DirectoryCatalog.Refresh](http://r.duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.directorycatalog.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does update already loaded assemblies. It only checks for file deletions and additions. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842417/850119) for a crude work-around. Note thought that I'm not sure if such an approach is thread-safe or production-ready since I have only tested simple scenarios. Another approach would be to create your own DirectoryCatalog that can handle updates as well. The MEF source code is available (as it is for the rest of the framework). The tricky part is thread-safety since the DirectoryCatalog implementation is using Microsoft's internal classes for locking.